# How to represent a series as a list?

Tags: python, arrays, variables, series

Is it possible to represent a series so that it is reusable, i.e. so that it can be stored in a variable?

Something like:

```
from collections import Counter

def myFunction(arr: List[int]) -> int:
    c = Counter(arr)
    s = k for k in c if c[k] == k
```

This doesn't work, throws error:

```
    s = k for k in c if c[k] == k
          ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what `Counter` is, what `arr` is and what you mean with "series". Maybe you want a list comprehension? `s = [k for k in c if c[k] == k]`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you are asking. It seems you already know how to store things in a variable. What the example code is failing at is using proper syntax of a *`list`* comprehension, which has nothing to do with storing the result in a variable. However, seeing how close it is to the actual syntax and that you apparently know that this is a `list`, you practically have that covered as well already.

Comment: Yes I didn't know about list comprehension.

Comment: @Dronakuul, w3schools is less of a dumpster fire than it once was, but it's _never_ the best resource to recommend. Official sources are always better. (Same with Geeksforgeeks.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" and similar mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-and-similar-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i)